# for-loops to apply a function and write the output as a data frame in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame with 3 columns. Column 1 in `Subject_ID` (is a `factor` with 44 levels) and column 2 is `types` (`factor` with 5 levels). So, each subject has all five types. Each 'types' is iterated 10 times. The third column is a dependent variable which is `numeric` (i.e., column name is  `depv`).  The number of rows in the data frame is thus 44 x 5 x 10  = 2200.  I want to apply a R function called

```
sens.slope(X, conf.level = 0.95)
```

for each `Subject_ID` and  then for each `type`. The function is applied to the 10 values under `depv` column for each `type`(for each `Subject_ID`).

This function gives  two values (a `z` and `p` value) as output. I want to create a new data-frame with same `Subject_ID` and `types` and append its `z` and `p` values against each `Subject_ID` and `types`.

Thus the length of the new data frame will be 44 x 5 = 220 rows. And, since each `types` has two values the columns will be 5 x 2 = 10 (excluding the `Subject_ID` column).

I am new to R and I have started to explore some one else's script. I know I need to write a for loop for this. But, I have no idea how to write. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's better to follow the link to provide a useul example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, sens.slope(depv, conf.level = 0.95), by = .(Subject_ID, types) ]`